# Change validation message for a custom validation rule in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

I'm trying to write a custom validation rule in Laravel to ensure that every email in a comma separated list is not on a suppression list. I already have a different rule that verifies if every email in the comma separated list is a valid email, so I don't check that here.

The code above works fine, but I have two questions:

1. Can I do this better?
2. How can I modify the error message to include the email address that's not correct? I want it to say something like `"The email address test@example.com is on the suppression list and will not be used for sending"`.

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $emails = explode(',', $value);

    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        $onSuppressionList = $this->suppressionListManager->find($email);
        
        if ($onSuppressionList) {
            return false;
        }               
    }

    return true;
}

public function message()
{
    return 'The validation error message.';
}
```

Comment: public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $emails = explode(',', $value);
 
 
  $onSuppressionList = $this->suppressionListManager->whereIn('email',$emails)->exists();

  
       
        
        if ($onSuppressionList) {
            return false;
        }               
    }

    return true;
}

Comment: what about this ?.not sure i am guessing you can check wherein  emails

Comment: `SuppressionListManager` is an utility class. It's not an Eloquent model. That part is fine, no need to change it.

Comment: i posted answer.let me know if any issues

Answer (score 1):

Declare property called `$suppressionList` like below

```
  private $suppressionList=[];
```

then change passes as

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $emails = explode(',', $value);


        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $onSuppressionList = $this->suppressionListManager->find($email);

            if ($onSuppressionList) {

                $this->suppressionList[]=$email;
            }
        }

        if(count($this->suppressionList)){

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

then in custom message

```
 public function message()
    {
        $emails=implode(",",$this->onSuppressionList);
        return 'The email address '.$emails.'is on the suppression list and will not be used for sending';
    }
```

For appending emails in message you can use `sprintf` too